# Codeigniter pagination problem

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, limit, offset

I basically can’t get the pagination bit to work, I did before I changed my database query and now I’m stuck.

My model looks like:

```
function get_properties($limit, $offset) {
   $location = $this->session->userdata('location');
   $property_type = $this->session->userdata('property_type');
   if($property_type == 0) 
   {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM properties ";
   }
   // more queries here
   $sql .= " LIMIT ".$limit.", ".$offset.";";
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      $this->session->set_userdata('num_rows', $query->num_rows());
      return $query->result_array();    
      return FALSE;
      }
   }
}
```

and my controller looks like:

```
function results() {
   $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/properties/results';
   $config['per_page'] = '3';
   $data['properties_results'] = $this->properties_model->get_properties($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
   $config['total_rows'] = $this->session->userdata('num_rows');
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $config['full_tag_open']='<div id="pages">';
   $config['full_tag_close']='</div>';
   $data['links']=$this->pagination->create_links();
   $this->load->view('properties_results',$data);
}
```

please help…its screwing up!

Comment: Not related to your question but please be aware that you may have a MySQL injection vulnerability in your code when you directly alter the query like that. You should use parameter binding for that, CI supports it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is that you never get the total_rows. You get the total_rows via this query, but it already has an offset and a limit:

```
$sql .= " LIMIT ".$limit.", ".$offset.";";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

To fix this you should add a function to your model:

```
function get_all_properties()
{
    return $this->db->get('properties');
}
```

Then in your controller, instead of:

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->session->userdata('num_rows');
```

Do:

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->properties_model->get_all_properties()->num_rows();
```

This should fix your pagination. Other than this your code has some strange things. E.g. `return FALSE;` in `get_properties` will NEVER execute. And why are you storing so much data in sessions. This is not necessary and not a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: Its ok I have fixed it, it was to do with the total rows returned.

The data in the sessions is from a search form, how else could I do this to pass information from page to page through codeigniter?

Comment: I have wrote tutorial about Cdeigniter Pagination. Please have a look and give your suggestions https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/